# Monero Genesis transaction & nonce

Tags: genesisblock

I've seen the monero genesis-tx breakdown

```
version 01 unlock time (varint, height, 60 here) 3c vin length (value in) 01 vin #1 (of 1) type (gen, 0xff) ff height for gen input 00 vout length (value out) 01 output #1 (of 1) amount (17592186044415 as varint) ffffffffffff03 output #1 type (to key, 0x02) 02 output #1 key (32 bytes) 9b2e4c0281c0b02e7c53291a94d1d0cbff8883f8024f5142ee494ffbbd088071 extra length in bytes (varint, here 33) 21 extra pubkey tag (0x01) 01 transaction pubkey (32 bytes) 7767aafcde9be00dcfd098715ebcf7f410daebc582fda69d24a28e9d0bc890d1
```

Does one simply change the output key and pub key, recompile and run the daemon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objective is to have a unique genesis block.

You could achieve this by altering the genesis transaction, for example by altering the output key and transaction public key so that your own wallet can be the beneficiary of the funds created in the genesis transaction. An easy way to do this would be to create a wallet address and then create a transaction destined for your wallet on the main Monero network. You could then use a blockchain explorer to inspect the tx public key and output one-time public key, and copy/paste that into the genesis transaction.

But if you don't care about getting access to the funds mined in the genesis transaction, you can leave the genesis transaction alone and simply change the nonce that is assigned to the genesis block.

If you're getting errors then please copy and paste the actual error messages into your question so that someone might be able to better understand specifically what you are doing wrong. My guess would be that your genesis block is fine and that the issue is related to aspects of setting up the daemon that are unrelated to the validity of your new genesis block. Therefore please document what you've tried, other than simply changing the contents of the genesis block.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes sense, basically i'm going to perform a transaction on the Monero mainnet to get the tx used for my genesis block. I appreciate this response so much, thanks again.