# output_tx on Genesis Block

Tags: genesisblock

I made a monero fork and generated a genesis block with a new one-time P but i never see the first reward in my wallet.

Can somebody tell me what is the **index_output** used on the output of a custom genesis block. ?

i mean, in order to create an output pub key we do

P=Hs(8rA || i)G+B

A = Pub_view_key , B = Pub_spend_key , **i = index**

so, i have to do it with i = 1 ? or i = 0 ?, is it the same to do Hs(8rA || 0) than Hs(8rA).

Comment: did u use bc for P=Hs(8rA || i)G+B can u write what did u do more concretly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the output index. Assuming you just have one output (all the reward to a single output), just use `0`. E.g. `P=Hs(8rA || 0)G+B`.

Comment: hi, i tried P=Hs(8rA || 0)G+B , put P on the **tx_gen_hex** , started mining successfully , but still not seeing the genesis block reward on my wallet. only the the rewards starting at height 1. any ideas why ?  is related to the index or the wallet not processing well the genesis output_tx. ?

Comment: You are likely not constructing the transaction properly. See: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9917/monero-genesis-transaction-nonce-clarification

Comment: maybe i am doing it wrong. anyway i tried using an existing one-time P of a real transaction on the blockchain like you said. i used the transaction **https://xmrchain.net/tx/4b540773ddf9e819f0df47708f3d3c9f7f62933150b90edc89103d-36d42ca4b7** of the mastering monero seed example , used the stealth address **b3a500acfa163763ccf6d2c10262294f8c287df3e5cac6309408adf94dc50335** and the extra **011c9c4272cc738815c2d22c7d3c6ebfbb7a820a6c7a3b591288d5025003cde24b**, but no luck. i´ll keep looking my error.

Comment: I found the problem. it was not the one-time key generation. The wallet-cli does not process the genesis block , you have to force it. any way now i can continue on my lab. thanks for the help @jtgrassie .