# How to generate Genesis TX for custom fork

Tags: cryptonote

Hello Ive made a somwhat working fork after renaming all the stuff etc I thought it will be right to remove previous checkpoints so I did so(I know how to get those) and then the biggest problem came how to generate the Genesis Hash?(Yes Ive googled everywhere and nothing relevat showed up, all pointed here which I still does not understand [How can I create a new Monero genesis block?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/how-can-i-create-a-new-monero-genesis-block) )

Comment: This question has been asked *many* times before. See: https://monero.stackexchange.com/search?q=genesis

Comment: When you done reading the "How can I create.." answers,  
you can continue on [Monero Genesis transaction & nonce - clarification](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9917/monero-genesis-transaction-nonce-clarification)  
There's some more details.